# Airflow - Jinja template inside params (postgresoperator)

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I am using many Postgres operators inside my Airflow DAG (building it with a for loop) and I wanted to know if it's possible to pass a JINJA template to params to my operator like:

```
params = {'max_field': '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_max_field_' + table + '", key="max_field") }}'}
```

so that in the .sql file I would only need to have a query that looks like

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ... > '{{ params.max_field }}'
```

My problem is that I have so many queries now that doing directly

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ... > '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_max_field_table1'", key="max_field") }}'
```

has a lot of risks of errors (writing table2 instead of table1 for example when people do copy pastes).

I tried putting params in template_fields = ('sql', 'parameters', 'params') but it didn't work, it renders my query with '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_max_field_table1'", key="max_field") }}' instead of the value.

I also tried using parameters instead of params and then doing:

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ... > '%(max_field)s'
```

but then there are problems in my queries if there is a % in the query like:

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ... > '%(max_field)s' and text like '%hello%'
```

Comment: Did you find any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

`params` doesn't support Jinja template.

Comment: any alternate way?

Comment: one thing you can do is `open` the .sql file, and format it (so no params, just a `{max_field}` waiting to be formatted) before you pass it to the `sql` field of your operator